# What is the equivalent to EditItemIndex of DataList in a ListView control?

Tags: .net, databound-controls

Acutallly I want to fire item editing events.
But how do I find the control?
I mean to say as we find the control in edititem event of DataList using EditItemIndex. What is the equivalent to EditItemIndex in a ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mean this:

```
    protected void lvDocs_ItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        lvDocs.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        //do whatever
    }//lvDocs_ItemEditing
```

Comment: it shows an error my dear that is :"property or indexer 'system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.edititem' cannot be assigned to --it is read only"  Now twll what i do to perform that what modifications require to correct that